# Grunt Not Resizeing Images

Tags: image, gruntjs, responsive, responsive-images

I'm trying to re-size and compress 8 images on a website so I resize and compress the images. However, when I implement the Grunt responsive images task it says success, but not for the parameters I have entered. Specifically, it indicates:

> `Running "responsive_images:dev" (responsive_images) task`
>
> `Resized 8 files for 120x110`

However, for the responsive images input, I have:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  responsive_images: {
    dev: {
      options: {
        engine: 'im',
        sizes: [{         
          width: 1600,
          suffix: '_large_2x',
          quality: 30
        }]
      },

      /*
      You don't need to change this part if you don't change
      the directory structure.
      */
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        src: ['*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
        cwd: 'images_src/',
        dest: 'images/'
      }]
    }
  },
```

How can I get Grunt to accurate resize the images according to the width, suffix, and quality shown?

The rest of the Grunt file states,

```js
    // ...

    clean: {
      dev: {
        src: ['images'],
      },
    },

    /* Generate the images directory if it is missing */
    mkdir: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          create: ['images']
        },
      },
    },

    /* Copy the "fixed" images that don't go through processing into the images/directory */
    copy: {
      dev: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: 'images_src/fixed/*.{gif,jpg,png}',
          dest: 'images/'
        }]
      },
    },
  });
  
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mkdir');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'mkdir', 'copy', 'responsive_images']);

};
```

I have included a screen shot of the file structure of the images. I just want them to appear in one of the directories, but they don't appear anywhere. I would have thought they would appear in the images/ directory because that is specified in the dest for responsive images.

[image: Image Directory]

Comment: Is your intention to resize all images _(.gif, .jpg, and .png)_ in the `images_src/fixed/` directory and save the resultant resized images (at 1600px wide) to the `images/fixed/` directory? This might seem like an odd question to be asked, however your question doesn't explicitly state your intent. Perhaps you can edit your question to indicate: **1**. a snippet of your source directory structure, and; **2**. Your desired/resultant directory structure after resizing occurs. It may increase your chance of getting a suitable answer/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try configuring your `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images');

  grunt.initConfig({
    responsive_images: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          engine: 'im',
          upscale: true, // <-- 1. Set `upscale` to `true` if you want images
                         //        with a width of less than 1600px wide to
                         //        also be resized to 1600px wide.
          sizes: [{         
            width: 1600,
            suffix: '_large_2x',
            quality: 30
          }]
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: ['**/*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
          cwd: 'images_src/',
          dest: 'images/'
        }]
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dev: {
        src: ['images']
      },
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean:dev', 'responsive_images:dev']);
};
```

**Notes**

1. The `mkdir` and `copy` tasks have been omitted. It's not necessary to create the destination directory and copy the image files as [grunt-responsive-images](https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images) can handle those tasks for you.
2. The `options` object for the `responsive_images` task now includes the `upscale` property with its value set to `true`. This will ensure that any images with a width of less than 1600px wide are also resized/upscaled to 1600px wide. Just delete it or set its value to `false` if you only want images with a width greater than 1600px to be resized.
3. When you now run `grunt` via your CLI using the gist above, something similar to the following will be logged to your console:

   > `Running "responsive_images:dev" (responsive_images) task`
   >
   > `Resized 8 files for 1600`